# Illegal Seek with really_input_string on stdin

Tags: ocaml

I am retrofitting some code to accept input from stdin (in addition to files).

```
print_string (really_input_string stdin (in_channel_length stdin))
```

This works when I redirect stdin:-

```
$ ./a.out < /tmp/lorem.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
```

But otherwise fails without waiting for input from me:-

```
$ ./a.out
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("Illegal seek")
$
```

Or:-

```
$ cat /tmp/lorem.txt | ./a.out 
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("Illegal seek")
```

How do I get the latter also to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what system you're using.

The Unix seek operation is meaningful only for regular files, i.e., files stored on disk (or similar randomly addressible media). In the usual Unix implementation, a seek on a terminal device or a pipe is just ignored. However, it appears that in the system you're using these are treated as an error. This makes me suspect you're not using a Unix-like (or sufficiently Unix-like) system.

At any rate the problem seems to be that `in_channel_length` seeks to the end of the file to determine how big it is. In your system this doesn't work when the input is coming from a terminal or a pipe.

It's hard to see how the code would work as expected even on a Unix system when input comes from a pipe or terminal.

I suggest you write your own loop to read until you see EOF.

Here's a crude implementation that's probably good enough for a text file:

```
let my_really_read_string in_chan =
    let res = Buffer.create 1024 in
    let rec loop () =
        match input_line in_chan with
        | line ->
            Buffer.add_string res line;
            Buffer.add_string res "\n";
            loop ()
        | exception End_of_file -> Buffer.contents res
    in
    loop ()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. This is what I ended up doing. Btw I am on Debian.

Comment: I just tried on two different Linux systems and indeed I see this error. I don't see it under macOS (which is where I initially did a quick check). This is very good to know, thanks!